# Bluetooth has to be enabled manually - Ubuntu 22.04 Lenovo Legion

Tags: boot, bluetooth, lenovo, 22.04

After upgrading to the latest BIOS (`J2CN40WW`) on `Legion 5 Pro 16IAH7H Laptop (Lenovo) - Type 82RF`, Bluetooth is not enabled after boot on Ubuntu 22.04.

I need to manually open settings and enable Bluetooth at which point it starts to work. This was not an issue with an older BIOS (v32 something).

Any ideas what could be wrong?

```
$ uname -a
Linux laptop 5.15.0-41-generic #44-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 22 14:20:53 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
$ sudo journalctl -u bluetooth.service -b
Jul 15 11:52:24 laptop systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Jul 15 11:52:24 laptop bluetoothd[2051]: Bluetooth daemon 5.64
Jul 15 11:52:24 laptop systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Jul 15 11:52:24 laptop bluetoothd[2051]: Starting SDP server
Jul 15 11:52:24 laptop bluetoothd[2051]: Bluetooth management interface 1.21 initialized
Jul 15 11:52:24 laptop bluetoothd[2051]: Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12)
Jul 15 11:52:42 laptop bluetoothd[2051]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.93 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Jul 15 11:52:42 laptop bluetoothd[2051]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.93 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Jul 15 11:52:42 laptop bluetoothd[2051]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.93 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_453
Jul 15 11:52:42 laptop bluetoothd[2051]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.93 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_453
Jul 15 11:52:42 laptop bluetoothd[2051]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.93 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_512
Jul 15 11:52:42 laptop bluetoothd[2051]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.93 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_512
Jul 15 11:52:42 laptop bluetoothd[2051]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.93 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_552
Jul 15 11:52:42 laptop bluetoothd[2051]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.93 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_552
```

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep -i bluetooth
[   11.000350] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   11.000364] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[   11.000365] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   11.000367] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   11.000368] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   11.000370] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   11.498471] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 0
[   11.498485] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[   11.498489] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[   11.498492] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[   11.498494] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[   11.498498] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[   11.498506] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader timestamp 2019.40 buildtype 1 build 38
[   11.507269] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-0040-0041.sfi
[   13.065574] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[   13.066501] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1522684 usecs
[   13.066621] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
[   13.084524] Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 17556 usecs
[   13.084875] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-0040-0041.ddc
[   13.087502] Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed
[   13.091586] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware timestamp 2022.5 buildtype 1 build 38020
[   14.644428] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   14.644431] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   14.644434] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   32.265356] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   32.265361] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   32.265363] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   45.164334] Bluetooth: HIDP (Human Interface Emulation) ver 1.2
[   45.164340] Bluetooth: HIDP socket layer initialized
[   45.165120] input: Magic Keyboard with Numeric Keypad Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-10/3-10:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256/0005:004C:026C.000A/input/input29
[   45.165341] input: Magic Keyboard with Numeric Keypad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-10/3-10:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256/0005:004C:026C.000A/input/input30
[   45.165495] hid-generic 0005:004C:026C.000A: input,hidraw9: BLUETOOTH HID v1.07 Keyboard [Magic Keyboard with Numeric Keypad] on bc:6e:e2:36:61:30
[   45.488406] input: Magic Keyboard with Numeric Keypad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-10/3-10:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256/0005:004C:026C.000A/input/input31
[   45.488750] apple 0005:004C:026C.000A: input,hidraw9: BLUETOOTH HID v1.07 Keyboard [Magic Keyboard with Numeric Keypad] on bc:6e:e2:36:61:30
```

After the boot when Bluetooth is not working yet:

```
$ rfkill list 1
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

Running `sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth` enables Bluetooth.
BIOS does not have a Bluetooth configuration.

Comment: if the answer is not good enough leave a pm for me and Ill revisit + edit if possible. Or remove it ;)

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add output of `rfkill list`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
rfkill list 1
```

should show "no" at both lines:

```
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
  Soft blocked: no
  Hard blocked: no
```

If soft blocked is yes it is a software related reason. If hard blocked is yes it is a hardware related reason. Please edit the question with the command and result you get.

You need a ...

```
sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth
```

and if that does not unblock the soft lock do a ...

```
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

and check again.

If you need to re-apply this after a reboot your BIOS might have bluetooth disabled so have a look there: as you updated your BIOS it might have been set to disabled (like a factory reset). You might also need a

```
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
```

after the `rfkill`.

Both commands should be needed one time and on reboot keep the state you left it in. If not please leave a comment.

---

If these works please test one of these and use it as a permanent solution (only one of the two is needed):

- add `rfkill.default_state=1` to the GRUB boot options (1st during a boot, if this works do `vi /etc/default/grub`, find `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`, and add at the end `rfkill.default_state=1` (with a space) save and do `sudo update-grub`).

  (you revert this by removing the string you added)
- Blacklisting (pilot6'scomment) would be

  ```
  sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
  ```

  and adding

  ```
  blacklist ideapad_laptop
  ```

  (you revert this by removing the line you added)

This [old bug](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/ce363c2bcb2303e7fad3a79398db739c6995141b) seems relevant to this (though is about unblocking wifi and not just BT)

Comment: After boot "Soft blocked" is yes, "Hard blocked" is no.
`sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth` enables bluetooth properly. The BIOS does not have any bluetooth setting.
I'm looking for a solution to permanently enable bluetooth without running the command, if possible.

Comment: Another option is to blacklist `ideapad_laptop`. Probably it needs a quirk for the new UEFI. It treats it like blocked. Needs testing though.

Comment: You guys are geniuses, love you all! `rfkill.default_state=1` did not help, but blacklisting `ideapad_laptop` did. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: @mike naaah pilot6 is the genius :-)  I cleaned up my comments.